# adding a highchart into wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, highcharts

I'm trying to add a highchart to a custom page template.

So far I've added the below code in-between header in the header file and the added the div into the page template. The issue is that the chart is not showing in my page template.

What could be the reason why it is not showing?

In header file between  tags

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#chart-container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center

        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'Marts', 'April', 'Maj', 'Juni','Juli', 'Aug', 'Septemper', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],labels:
        {
          enabled: false
        }

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels:
        {
          enabled: false
        },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: 'Kr.'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
            credits: {
            enabled: false
         },

        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });
});</script>
```

in the page template I've added the following

```
<div id="chart-container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: what does the console say? (ctrl+shift+i->console tab in chrome)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedlocalhost/:23 (anonymous function)

dunno if it is related to the issue

Comment: also, what does the PHP error log for the template say? (I guess that would be on your error_log server file if you are using apache, or on screen if you have display errors enables on php.ini or ini_set() on your wordpress config...)

Comment: Alright `Uncaught reference $ is not defined` means you are not loading jquery, qhich is a requirement for highcharts

Comment: (just add something like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your header, right before including highcharts library

Comment: that returns Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function?page_id=6608:24 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 jjquery.min.js:2 k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load something similar to the jsfiddle example from highcharts.com: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Your first error, `Uncaught reference: $ is not defined` on your Javascript console when loading the page means you are not loading jQuery library, which is a requirement for highcharts.

You have to load jquery before highcharts. The example uses jquery 1.9.1, so you should load that version (or higher) before including the highcharts library. E.g.

```
... 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

...
```

(Be aware that althought this method should work, WordPress has its own and more appropriate way to include jQuery or any javascript library on a page template to avoid conflicts. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script )

Your second error is that you have to wait for the container to exist (dom ready) before trying to manipulate its content.

You can do that by using jQuery's document ready function. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready({
    $('#chart-container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center

        },

    ...

    });
  });

... 

</script>
```

(More info on http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ )

These related answers might help you too:

[How could I embed a HighCharts interactive graph into a wordpress 3.5.1 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557709/how-could-i-embed-a-highcharts-interactive-graph-into-a-wordpress-3-5-1-page)

[highcharts and wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403702/highcharts-and-wordpress)

Lastly, you might be interested on a couple of FOS wordpress plugins that already do the heavy work of creating a highchart for you:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rj-quickcharts/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/table2chart/

Comment: i changed you're jquery.min.js url to this and it worked  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

cheers

Comment: ups, yeah sorry I missed the inclusion I proposed was using https:// instead of http://. http:// should work too, but the generic // is more appropriate for this case.